# How to avoid double columns (predefined columns + selectcommand)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview with predefined columns and a selectcommand. Why do I get the columns twice? I want to keep the predefined columns and the selectcommand, but avoid getting the columns double.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMeldingen" runat="server" 
            AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="MyDataSource" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Melder" HeaderText="Melder" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Onderwerp" HeaderText="Onderwerp" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="overflow:auto; width: 500px; height: 150px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOmschrijving" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Omschrijving")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fasedatum" HeaderText="Fasedatum" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Niveau 1" HeaderText="Niveau 1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Niveau 2" HeaderText="Niveau 2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Outlook_ID" HeaderText="OutlookID" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HELPDESK_OUTLOOKConnectionString3 %>" />
```

This code shows how I use the selectcommand:

```
protected void MenuTabs1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        string select = @"SELECT 
        aanvrager.werknemersnaam AS Melder,
        hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_titel AS Onderwerp, 
        hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_omschrijving AS Omschrijving, 
        hd_aanvraag_fase.fase_datum AS Fasedatum, 
        hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau_omschrijving AS 'Niveau 1', 
        hd_melding_niveau_2.niveau_omschrijving AS 'Niveau 2',
        hd_aanvragen.outlook_id
        FROM hd_aanvragen
        INNER JOIN hd_meldingen         ON hd_meldingen.melding_id      =  hd_aanvragen.melding_id 
        INNER JOIN hd_melding_niveau_1  ON  hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau1_id = hd_meldingen.niveau1_id 
        INNER JOIN hd_melding_niveau_2  ON  hd_melding_niveau_2.niveau2_id = hd_meldingen.niveau2_id 
        INNER JOIN hd_aanvraag_fase     ON hd_aanvraag_fase.aanvraag_id =  hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_id
        INNER JOIN hd_statussen ON hd_statussen.status_id =  hd_aanvraag_fase.status_id 
        INNER JOIN  hd_werknemers AS oplosser ON oplosser.werknemer_Id =  hd_aanvraag_fase.werknemer_Id 
        INNER JOIN hd_werknemers  AS aanvrager ON aanvrager.werknemer_Id =  hd_aanvragen.werknemer_Id 
        WHERE hd_statussen.status_id = ";

        int index = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value);
        multiTabs1.ActiveViewIndex = index;
        int status = 0;
        if (index == 1)
            status = 2;
        else if (index == 2)
            status = 16;
        else if (index == 3)
            status = 17;
        else if (index == 4)
            status = 4;
        MyDataSource.SelectCommand = select + status;
    }
```

Comment: try add "AutoGenerateColumns=False"

Comment: that's it, you had to post it as an answer :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the AutoGenerateColumns property to your GridView with value "false".
That will let the GridView know that no columns should be automatically generated during the bind process.

Good luck! :)